# XSD to Java using JAXB with multi-level import failing

Tags: java, maven, xsd, jaxb2

I am facing an issue while creating Java classes from XSD using JAXB2.

please let me know if JAXB can handle this.

***Scenario:***

1) **Project A** has `a.xsd` and `b.xsd` with different name-spaces
`b.xsd` uses `a.xsd` with import name-space tag.

2) **Project B** has `c.xsd` and uses `b.xsd` by importing `b.xsd`.
Catalog is being used by `c.xsd` to find the `b.xsd` in the Maven JAR which is added as a dependency.

**ISSUE**:

**Project A** builds fine but **Project B** throws error as it could not find `a.xsd` which is internally used by b.xsd.

**ERROR**

> [ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ http://www.example.com/test2/test2.xsd{15,39}].
>       org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.example.com/test2/test2.xsd; lineNumber: 15; columnNumber: 39; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'addme:address' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)

***Project A***

**a.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/address" xmlns="http://www.example.com/address"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="address">

        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

**b.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/test2"
    xmlns="http://www.example.com/test2"
    xmlns:addme="http://www.example.com/address"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:import namespace="http://www.example.com/address" schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/address/address.xsd"/>

    <xs:element name="test2">
       <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="addme:address" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
     </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

***Project B***

**c.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/customer"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.example.com/customer"
    xmlns:test="http://www.example.com/test2" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:import namespace="http://www.example.com/test2"
        schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/test2/test2.xsd" />

    <xs:element name="customer">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="test:test2" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

**catalog file for project B**

> REWRITE_SYSTEM "http://www.example.com/test2" "maven:com.test.projectA:projectA:jar::!"

**Project A POM snippet**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <properties>
        <xsd.build.dir>${basedir}/src/main/resources</xsd.build.dir>
        <generated.source.location>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/src</generated.source.location>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.13.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <generateDirectory>${generated.source.location}</generateDirectory>
                    <schemaDirectory>${xsd.build.dir}</schemaDirectory>
                    <episode>true</episode>
                    <addIfExistsToEpisodeSchemaBindings>true</addIfExistsToEpisodeSchemaBindings>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                            <version>0.6.4</version>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-XtoString</arg>
                        <arg>-Xequals</arg>
                        <arg>-XhashCode</arg>
                    </args>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <phase>DISABLE_FORKED_LIFECYCLE_MSOURCES-13</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>
</project>

**PROJECT B POM** 

        <?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" .>

    <properties>
        <xsd.build.dir>${basedir}/src/main/resources</xsd.build.dir>
        <generated.source.location>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/src</generated.source.location>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test.projectA</groupId>
            <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.13.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <generateDirectory>${generated.source.location}</generateDirectory>
                    <schemaDirectory>${xsd.build.dir}</schemaDirectory>
                    <catalog>src/main/resources/catalog.cat</catalog>
                    <useDependenciesAsEpisodes>true</useDependenciesAsEpisodes>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                            <version>0.6.4</version>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-XtoString</arg>
                        <arg>-Xequals</arg>
                        <arg>-XhashCode</arg>
                    </args>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <phase>DISABLE_FORKED_LIFECYCLE_MSOURCES-13</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I can't see a catalog entry for `http://www.example.com/address`. It's probably trying to load it from the location specified in _b.xsd_, which is `http://www.example.com/address/address.xsd`.

Comment: thanks @teppic. actually I tried that before without luck, I thought the same. basically when I build projecA which has a and b xsd, that builds fine, the issue arriases in project which has c xsd ->references b xsd -> references a xsd. a and b are provided as dependencies and may be it's not able to get "a" from the level of "c" when it's parsing but not sure if there is any specific way to tell system or in catalog...

Answer (score 0):

Your catalog file needs to rewrite the locations of both xsds:

```
REWRITE_SYSTEM "http://www.example.com/test2/test2.xsd" "maven:com.test.projectA:projectA:jar::!/b.xsd"
REWRITE_SYSTEM "http://www.example.com/address/address.xsd" "maven:com.test.projectA:projectA:jar::!/a.xsd"
```

Note that these are rewrite rules, not `PUBLIC` rules. The left hand side of each entry is the `systemLocation` used in the xsds, not the namespace. `PUBLIC` rules won't work for you because your xsds specify a `systemLocation`, and there's a bug in xjc that prevents `PUBLIC` rules from working when a `systemLocation` is specified.

Also check that your xsds are being copied to the root of the published jar, and that their names match the ones used in the catalog.

Reference: [Using-Catalogs](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Using-Catalogs)

Comment: If I use full path as you mentioned, it won't find the b.xsd as well.               "http://www.example.com/test2/test2.xsd" "maven:com.test.projectA:projectA:jar::!/b.xsd"    it is only taking as what I had before like this     "http://www.example.com/test2" "maven:com.test.projectA:projectA:jar::!"     I mean only the namespace without xsd

Comment: I've checked that this works with your example code (published maven project and maven urls in the catalog included). Check that your system locations match the urls in the catalog exactly and that the xsds have been copied to the published jar to the paths specified in the cataolog.